# What is the difference between "gksudo nautilus" and "sudo nautilus"?

Tags: sudo, security, root, gksudo

I've been using `gksudo nautilus` and `sudo nautilus` through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

What's the difference? They look very similar!

Comment: a very helpful explanation / discussion including many screenshots: http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo

Comment: Related: [Why is gksu no longer installed by default?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default)

Comment: Related: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo):

> You should **never** use normal `sudo` to start graphical applications as
>   root. You should use `gksudo` (`kdesudo` on Kubuntu) to run such programs.
>   `gksudo` sets `HOME=/root`, and copies `.Xauthority` to a `tmp` directory.
>   This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by root.

Please note that this is primarily about *configuration files*. If you run Nautilus as `root`, even with `gksu`/`gksudo`, and you create a file or folder anywhere with it (including in your home directory), that file or folder will be owned by `root`. But if you run Nautilus (or most other graphical applications) as `root` with `sudo`, they may save their *configuration files* in your home directory (rather than `root`'s home directory). Those configuration files may be owned by `root` and inaccessible when you're not running as root, which can severely mess up your settings, and may even keep some applications from working altogether.

The solution, once you have made this mistake, is to find the configuration files and delete them or [`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chown.1.html) them back to belonging your non-`root` user. Many such files start with a `.` or are contained in a directory that starts with a `.`. Some are located inside the `.config` folder in your home directory. To see files and folders that start with a `.` in Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (this *shows hidden files*.) To see them with [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ls.1.html), use the `-a` (or `-A`) flag.

To find if there are files not owned by you in your home directory, you can use the following command in a terminal:

```
find $HOME -not -user $USER -exec ls -lad {} \;
```

which will list all files under the home directory not owned by the user.

Comment: I've already used 'sudo nautilus'. That means that my home directory is now owned by root? (PS: my English is not perfect)

Comment: No, it means that while you were running Nautilus as root, any files that it created in your home directory will be owned by root. This could include thumbnails and other supporting files that Nautilus creates automatically.

Comment: . The quoted segemnet you used has puzzled me since I first read it; specifically where it says: *"This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by root."* .. I tested this today by creating some test files, on 10.04, 10.04(VM), 10.10(VM), and no matter how I started sudo/gksudo (Terminal->Nautilus, Terminal->gedit, Alt+F2...)... all cases caused my newly created to be owned by "root", with group "root".. Maybe I've missed something but I think that part of the quoted segment is misleading people...

Comment: Hmm, I was just quoting the wiki page. I don't really have a deep understanding of the difference between the two tools. Perhaps someone on http://unix.stakexchange.com can help?

Comment: @Peter.O I've expanded this answer to address that question and explain exactly which files are treated differently with `sudo`, via `gksu`/`gksudo`. (@ChrisWilson Feel free to roll back or shorten this edit if you feel it's not totally within the scope of your answer...it seems to me it is, but that's entirely your call.)

Answer (score 9):

Did you know there is a Nautilus add on called [nautilus-gksu [image: Install nautilus-gksu]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-gksu) which adds an "open as administrator" to nautilus' right click menu?

*Note: Not available in Ubuntu 12.04 and onward.*

Comment: `nautilus-gksu` is no longer available from Ubuntu 12.04 and onward.

Comment: And [your link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-gksu) only shows that it is available up to 11.10...

Answer (score 5):

If you start a graphical application with sudo you can mess up the ownership of your files which can cause your apps to break. Never do that. Check the [Community Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo):

> **You should never use normal sudo to
>   start graphical applications as Root**.
>   You should use gksudo (kdesudo on
>   Kubuntu) to run such programs. gksudo
>   sets HOME=~root, and copies
>   .Xauthority to a tmp directory. This
>   prevents files in your home directory
>   becoming owned by Root. (AFAICT, this
>   is all that's special about the
>   environment of the started process
>   with gksudo vs. sudo).

Answer (score 5):

### `sudo -H GUI-application-program`

In Ubuntu (17.10) 17.10.1 and probably future versions of Ubuntu, `gksu` and `gksudo` are deprecated. They work in Xorg but not Wayland. But you can use **`sudo -H`** to run GUI application programs without damage to your configuration files. Do *not* use plain `sudo`.

If you are running Wayland (the new graphical system that replaces Xorg), you need a command with `xhost` too.

```
xhost +si:localuser:root       # if Wayland
sudo -H nautilus --no-desktop
```

See the following link for more details,

[Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)

Answer (score 3):

sudo by default preserves your $HOME variable.  For example, if you run `sudo firefox` you will run with root privileges but your configuration.  If you change settings in this situation, you will end up with parts of your configuration owned by root instead of your user id.

Comment: I like the assertiveness of this answer.

Answer (score -2):

**Found in the file generated by the terminal command 'info gksudo':**

> gksu is a front-end to su and gksudo is a front-end to sudo. Their primary purpose is to run graphical commands that need root without the need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly.

I have found that, in many cases, the 'info' files have helpful descriptions as well as useful information on options. I would strongly suggest that learning about any command first start with accessing the 'info' file on that command.

For the beginner, in the terminal, type or paste the command info with the command name in which you are interested as a parameter. The format is `info [command_name]` (remember not to include the command prompt or the brackets). Suggested terminal entries for the beginner are:

```
$ info
$ info info
```

Answer (score -3):

If you choose gksudo nautilus, You ask your password graphically. With sudo, you ask it in a terminal

Comment: That's not the only difference, and often is not the most important difference. (See some of the other answers here.)