# What is the difference between gksudo and gksu?

Tags: gksu, gksudo

Is there any difference between the behavior of `gksu foo` and `gksudo foo`? 
Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: nb: as of ubuntu 18.04, gksu/gksudo are deprecated (gone) and replaced by policykit (polkit), being that they were unsupported and unsecure, which is as of now (post-2018) what they have in common ;-)  (see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default?noredirect=1&lq=1 )

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Both files point to the same place:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gksudo 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2010-09-27 18:23 /usr/bin/gksudo -> gksu
```

... `gksudo` is symlinked to `gksu`. But this doesn't mean they *do* the same things, far from it.

Applications can detect the command used to run it. This is typically `argv[0]` in C-style languages or `$0` in Bourne-style shell scripts. The application can look at that and in this case, actually it changes how it works. The first indication of this is in the `man gksu` page:

```
gksu  is  a  frontend  to  su  and gksudo is a frontend to sudo.
```

If you look in the source (`apt-get source gksu`) for `run_mode`, you'll see how it detects this:

```
  { /* support gksu_sudo_run */
    gchar *myname = g_path_get_basename (argv[0]);
    if (!strcmp(myname, "gksudo"))
      run_mode = SUDO_MODE;
    g_free (myname);
  }
```

You can override this with the `--su-mode`/`-w` and `--sudo-mode`/`-S` arguments (so you can run equivalent commands without needing the `gksudo` symlink... But that's up to you.

If you want to know how these "modes" really differ, there's only a bit of escaping in `gksu`. You need to follow it into `libgksu`. This is the library that actually checks permissions before handing off to the system.

If no mode is specified (eg you call `gksu` without arguments) by the time it reaches  `libgksu`, [it will check Gconf (as Stefano points out)](https://askubuntu.com/a/21038/449) and if it still can't decide, it'll default to the `su` mode.

Comment: To add to Oli's comment; Though gksudo is symlinked to gksu, In Ubuntu, by default we will _only_ be using gksudo because we have the /apps/gksu/sudo-mode enabled. So unless someone forces  the --su-mode option gksu is not used.

Comment: @Oli: I wouldn't immediately conclude that there is no difference just because it's a symlink. Look at busybox, depending on the name of the symlink, different actions are performed. In this case, I don't know if it's true or not, but AFAIK it's indeed the case.

Comment: -1, very misleading: software may behave differently depening on what name was used to invocate them. For example `bash` turns on POSIX strict mode when invoked as `sh`. And `gksu` ***is*** also aware of invocation name.

Comment: Using internet on my cellphone with too small screen and too large fingers, I must have unintentionally downvoted. I upvoted to compensate :)

Answer (score 38):

In Ubuntu (!), there is no difference.

- `gksu` would normally **log in the root user** and run an app on this session. However, on Ubuntu, it defaults to using the "sudo mode", which is equivalent of running `gksudo`. This is because on ubuntu, you [can't log in as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root) by default.
- `gksudo` is the graphical equivalent of `sudo` (and as Oli points out, just a symbolic link to gksu)

From the gconf entry of gksu:

[image]

Furthermore, on the difference between sudo and gksudo:

> You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as root. You should use gksudo (kdesudo on Kubuntu) to run such programs. gksudo sets HOME=~root, and copies .Xauthority to a tmp directory. This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by root. (AFAICT, this is all that's special about the environment of the started process with gksudo vs. sudo).
>  — *(from the [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical%20sudo) via [Chris Wilson](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus/11766#11766))*

Answer (score 15):

I know that this is an old thread, but I've been [asked to tell you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default-in-13-04?noredirect=1#comment362442_284306) about a subtle but essential difference between `gksu` and `gksudo`.

Although I have looked long and hard, I cannot find a documented difference anywhere, and yet it does exist. I have also not found out why there is a difference. I found this the hard way when I accidentally deleted some system files precisely because of this difference (discussed in a [thread in Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1819589)) — I had been using `gksu`, but since then I have made sure always to use `gksudo`.

To summarise, try this.

1. Create three files in some folder:
   `touch abc`
   `touch abc.tmp`
   `touch abctmp`
2. Run the following six commands. The first five give the same (expected) result (i.e. just `abc.tmp`) whereas the sixth includes an extra file (`abctmp`) that it shouldn't.

   ```
   find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.tmp' -print
   sudo find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.tmp' -print
   gksudo -- find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.tmp' -print
   gksudo --su-mode -- find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.tmp' -print
   gksu --sudo-mode -- find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.tmp' -print
   gksu -- find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.tmp' -print
   ```

Imagine the problems when you replace `-print` with `-delete` in the `find` command (which is exactly what happened to me, causing some system files to be deleted).

So, please use `gksudo` instead of `gksu`.

Comment: Just tried this on 12.04LTS.  Don't yet fully understand why but there is a difference.  The source code for gksu shows that `gksudo` is equivalent to typing `gksu --sudo-mode`

Comment: @WarrenHill — yes, in theory! But not in practice. I do not know why.

Comment: Interesting, and verified on 13.04. Definitely looks like a quote handling bug.

Comment: Filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+bug/1186676).

Comment: @l0b0 - thanks, I've added my vote to the bug.

Comment: The only one of those commands that gave me any output was the last one which printed `./abctmp`... And yes, I *did* create the files correctly :-/

Comment: @Seth, I have repeated the commands and I got the same results as always. I'm using 12.04; what version are you using? Did you cut-and-paste the commands correctly? Are you using Bash? Check the files `/etc/profile`, `~.profile` and `~.bashrc` for any changes that may affect the results. Otherwise I'm at a bit of a loss as to why you had an inconsistent result.