# How to run a command as a user whose login is disabled?

Tags: sudo, su

I am trying to use the su command to run an application as another user

In this case I am trying to run irssi

```
blah@ubuntu: su - [username] irssi
(enter password)

blah@ubuntu:
(nothing happens)

blah@ubuntu: su - [username] -c irssi
(nothing)
```

I run gksu and set same parameters and it works, and doesn't ask me for the user password. What is the issue? And how do I solve it?

I should note the user was created like this

```
adduser --system --disabled-login [username]
```

if it makes any difference....sigh.

Comment: aren't you forgetting -c flag to launch irssi ? (su -c irssi)

Comment: tried that too...tried a thousand things...why so hard to runas WTF thats exactly as the man page wants it...but nothing happens grrrr

Comment: could it just be that `irssi` has an issue and that the su command works?

Comment: Has the ´[username]´ proper rights to run  irssi?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> This answer should still help you, even taking the edits to the
>   question into account. In particular, an account created with
>   `--disabled-login` has no password set and no other means of *logging
>   in*, but it should still be possible to use `sudo` (explained below)
>   to run commands or a shell as the user. This is, in fact, how the
>   `root` account is set up in Ubuntu.

### There are multiple problems with the command `su - irssi`.

This command tries to *start a shell* owned by **a user named `irssi`**.

It will fail if:

- There is no `irssi` user.
- The `irssi` user's account is disabled.
- The `irssi` user's account is disabled for interactive login. Sometimes an account is permitted to use services like FTP but prohibited from logging in normally by setting their shell to something that quits immediately, like `/bin/false`. Then a login immediately ends, with no message.
- The password you're entering is not correct for the `irssi` user.

The `-` flag makes it so the shell simulates an initial login shell--that is, so it's really very much like logging on as `irssi`. Without the `-` flag, if the `su` command succeeded, you'd still get a shell owned by `irssi`, but environment variables like `HOME` would be unchanged.

**If you instead want to run a program *called* `irssi`**, you must invoke `su` differently:

```
su username - -c irssi
```

If you leave out `-c username`, it's the same as `-c root`--it attempts to run the command as root.

**Alternatively you can start a shell and then run the command**:

1. Start the shell with `su username -`.
2. In the shell, run the command (`irssi`).
3. If you're done, leave the shell by running `exit`.

### Running Commands as `root`

If you want to run `irssi` as `root`, `su` is not the way to do it. Root logins are [disabled by default on Ubuntu, and there is only rarely any reason to re-enable them](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). If you have enabled `root` login, then you should be able to use `su` to become `root`. The reason it's unnecessary to enable the `root` account is that, whether or not you do, you can still run commands as `root` with `sudo`.

**When you run commands with `sudo`, you put in *your* password, *not* the password of the user under whose identity you wish the command to run.** Only administrators may run arbitrary commands as `root` with `sudo` (unless you reconfigure `sudo` to allow others to do so, of course). So a user who is not allowed to administer the system is not allowed to run commands as `root` with their own password.

To run `irssi` as `root` with `sudo`:

```
sudo irssi
```

And you would enter *your* password when prompted, not `root`'s.

Except what password you enter, this does the same thing as:

```
su -c irssi
```

Except the `sudo` version can succeed because it doesn't require the `root` account to be enabled.

Like with `su`, you can use `sudo` to **run commands as another, non-`root` user**. To run `irssi` as **`username`** with `sudo`:

```
sudo -u username irssi
```

If you want `sudo` **to behave like `su -` with respect to `HOME`**--that is, you want to use the target user's `HOME` environment variables, you can run `sudo` with the `-H` flag:

```
sudo -H irssi
```

```
sudo -H -u username irssi
```

You can start a whole shell with `sudo`, like you can with `su`. Except for whose password you put in, this command has the same effect as `su`:

```
sudo -s
```

And this command has the same effect as `su -`:

```
sudo -i
```

(The `i` stands for *initial login shell*.)

You can start a shell as another user, too:

```
sudo -u username -s
```

```
sudo -u username -i
```

### Further Reading on `sudo`

**To learn more about `sudo`**, take a look at:

- [The Ubuntu community wiki.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)
- [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)
- [The upstream `sudo` site](http://www.sudo.ws/) (by the author of `sudo`).
- [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html)
- [What are the benefits of sudo over su?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135428/what-are-the-benefits-of-sudo-over-su)
- [Why is there no option to login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root)

### Why did `gksu` work when `su` didn't?

`gksu` probably worked *by running `sudo`*.

`gksu` is a frontend for *both* `su` and `sudo`. In Ubuntu, it defaults to using `sudo` (since in Ubuntu, `su` is typically not used for becoming `root`, and is only a secondary way of becoming other, non-`root` users).

You can make `gksu` use `su` as the frontend by running `gksu --su-mode`.

You can find out whether `gksu` is in `su` mode or `sudo` mode, and (if you wish) change this setting, by running `gksu-properties`. This is a per-user setting.

When `gksu` is in `sudo` mode, it behaves the same as `gksudo`.

### Further Reading on `gksu`

- [This subsection of the Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo), on "graphical `sudo`".
- [`man gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html)
- [The upstream `gksu` website](http://www.nongnu.org/gksu/) (by the makers of `gksu`).
- [Stefano Palazzo's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/21038/22949) about explaining `gksu` vs. `gksudo` in Ubuntu.

---

### Post-Solution Analysis

You found ultimately that you were able to run the necessary command with:

```
sudo -u username irssi
```

<sup>(Which is of the techniques listed above.)</sup>

Ultimately, you reported two pieces of information, which are sufficient to explain why it was that other techniques had failed, but that had succeeded:

1. The **`username`** account was created with the `--disabled-login` flag, which makes it have *no password* (and no other means of logging in). Having no password doesn't mean it's possible to log in with a *blank password*. It means *no password* is sufficient to authenticate. In combination with the elimination of other means of authentication, this means **`username`** cannot authenticate at all.

   So all `su`-based solutions are out. `sudo` can work though, because with `sudo` you don't authenticate as the user you're about to impersonate. Instead, you have to be [authorized](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) to impersonate them, and you authenticate as yourself (i.e., enter your own password, not theirs).

   It's possible to set a password on the account, which removes this barrier to logging in:

   ```
   sudo passwd username
   ```

   However there might be a good reason the user is not allowed to log in. For example, if this user were allowed to log in, and logged in graphically, would bad problems arise from the user's environment or privileges being poorly suited to running X11 apps? If this user could log on, would that make it possible to log on remotely as that user (for machines where you have exposed network services)?

   If you ever want to re-disable it:

   ```
   sudo passwd -dl username
   ```

   *Related: [Re-disabling the `root` account after having temporarily enabled it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account)*
2. The **`username`** account has `/bin/false` as its login shell.

   When a shell like `bash` runs as your login shell, it sets up your environment and gives you an interactive prompt with which to control the machine.

   When `/bin/false` runs, on the other hand, it *does nothing*, and *reports failure*. (`/bin/true` does nothing and reports success.)

   The `false` and `true` commands are useful in scripting and for various testing purposes, but also for disabling an account so that when someone logs in, their login session immediately ends. That way, a password (or other means of authentication) can be enabled, and people can log in, just not for *shell access*. For example, if there is an FTP server, they could still access their account via FTP. If there is an SSH server, they wouldn't be able to get a shell via SSH, but they could still use `sftp` and `scp` to transfer files.

   Since **`username`**'s login shell was nonfunctional, commands like `su username`, `su - username`, `sudo -u username -s`, and `sudo -u username -i` could not work.

   But commands that don't give a shell, like `sudo -u username command` or `su username -c 'command'` could still work.

   Since *commands* can be run, you *can* change the user's login shell to something functional:

   ```
   sudo chsh -s /bin/bash username
   ```

   However, this should also be done with caution, as there may be a good reason to disable interactive logins for the user.

Here, **`username`** both had disabled password *and* "disabled" shell. The absence of any working password prevented all `su`-based solutions from working, while the absence of a working interactive login shell prevented all shell-spawning solutions from working (except manually invoking a shell, like `sudo -u username bash`).

`sudo -u username command` is what remained.

Comment: Sorry for the many edits while you were working on your answer. Wow. Thank you. When I do cat /etc/passwd the user I have configured has /bin/false at the end - so is this what is causing it to fail? any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: For whatever reason, using sudo -u username irssi works the treat. Thanks for your lengthy, well explained answer!

Comment: @db I'm glad it worked! (Btw, no need to apologize for editing, editing is very, very good, and your question will likely be useful for more other people too as a consequence of the edits.) As for your other questions, I've edit my answer to include an analysis section at the end.