# Is it a good thing to run virt-manager as sudo?

Tags: sudo, gui, virt-manager

I just installed qemu-kvm and virt-manager. But when i run virt-manager by clicking the icon it is not connecting to kvm. But when i run `$ sudo virt-manager` KVM connects.

i've been told that running GUI application with sudo is not a good thing.
So running virt-manager as root will cause any issues?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo adduser YOUR_USERNAME libvirt`, reboot your system, after that you won't need sudo to open virt-manager.

Comment: Is it a good idea to give the grocery delivery guy all your house keys including the key to the home safe where you keep money and jewelry? Running normal apps with `sudo` is like that.

Answer (score 5):

> I've been told that running GUI application with `sudo` is not a good
> thing.

What you've been told is a remnant of an old issue (tale) that is not an issue anymore. Some people will still warn you not to do so on Ubuntu without even knowing why!

Starting from Ubuntu 19.10 and later, you can run GUI applications with `sudo`.

The old issue was that `sudo` used to write and modify the applications configuration files in the current user's home directory changing their permissions and ownership from the current user to `root` which will render them inaccessible to the current user and thus mess up the current user's home directory's contents to the point that GUI applications might not run anymore or run with errors ... this, however, is not the case anymore. Starting from Ubuntu 19.10, using `sudo` with GUI applications will assume root's home directory and **not** the current user's home directory.

However, running applications (GUI or otherwise) with `sudo` gives them root's privileges and this might pose major security, stability and integrity problems and this one was and still the same so use precaution and common sense with it.

That said ... make sure your application needs `sudo` to function or otherwise you should refrain from using `sudo`.

---

> I just installed qemu-kvm and virt-manager. But when I run
> virt-manager by clicking the icon it is not connecting to kvm. But
> when I run `$ sudo virt-manager` KVM connects.

`virt-manager` is a desktop user interface for managing virtual
machines through `libvirt` and clearly doesn't need `sudo` to run ... what you, probably, need to do is add your user to the two groups `libvirt` and `kvm` as stated in the [installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation).

Comment: It still considered a bad idea to run any application with `sudo`, when `sudo` is cleary not needed to run that application.