# show hidden files doesn't work on nautilus, ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, nautilus, hidden-files

when I enter `sudo nautilus` on the terminal, enter any of my partitions and select show hidden files from the drop menu on the top right it doesn't select it and doesn't work.

Comment: No, i use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Please use `sudo -H nautilus`

Comment: @nobody no need for the `-H` on 22.04 … Please see https://askubuntu.com/q/1411511

Comment: @Raffa oh, have not noticed, because I prefer pkexec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install dbus-x11

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

Comment: thanks, so much @keops