# Difference between "select-editor" and "update-alternatives --config editor"

Tags: cron, update-alternatives, visudo

I'm looking at how Ubuntu selects a default editor, and I notice that to set the default editor for editing `crontabs`, I use `select-editor` while to set the default editor for `visudo` I use `update-alternatives --config editor`. Does anyone know the specific difference between these two? There's a lot of documentation explaining each one individually, but I haven't been able to figure out the difference between the two or why I have to set both.

For completeness, I want to note I know how to set the default editor by setting the EDITOR and VISUAL environment variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`select-editor`**](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/select-editor.1.html) is a per user selector ... It helps you select your default [`sensible-editor`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/sensible-editor.1.html) from all installed editors ... It affects the file `~/.selected_editor` i.e. for example on my system:

```bash
$ cat ~/.selected_editor
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/bin/nano"
```

Please see `man select-editor`:

> **select-editor**  provides  a  coherent  mechanism  for  selecting  and
> storing  a preferred sensible-editor on a per-user basis.  It lists
> the  available  editors  on  a  system  and interactively  prompts
> the user to select one.  The results are stored as SELECTED_EDITOR
> variable in ~/.selected_editor, which is sourced  and  used  by
> sensible-editor  command. SELECTED_EDITOR variable is overridden by
> the VISUAL and EDITOR environment variables.

[**`update-alternatives`**](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html), on the other hand, is a system-wide selector ... It helps you set the default behaviors e.g. editor that a system command calls ...  [`visudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/visudo.8.html) is such a command ... It does so by handling which editor `/usr/bin/editor` calls ... As a symbolic link i.e. for example on my system:

```bash
$ ls -l /usr/bin/editor /etc/alternatives/editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan  8  2022 /etc/alternatives/editor -> /bin/nano
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jan  8  2022 /usr/bin/editor -> /etc/alternatives/editor
```

Please see `man update-alternatives`:

> **update-alternatives**  creates,  removes,  maintains  and  displays
> information  about  the symbolic links comprising the Debian
> alternatives system.
>
> It is possible for several programs  fulfilling  the  same  or
> similar  functions  to  be installed  on  a  single  system at the
> same time.  For example, many systems have several text editors
> installed at once.  This gives choice to the users of a system,
> allowing each to use a different editor, if desired, but makes it
> difficult for a program to make a good choice for an editor to invoke
> if the user has not specified a particular preference.

Comment: I'm curious doesn't sudo use the root user? So wouldn't settings for sudo be found in /root? So the default editor for sudo would be found in /root/.selected_editor?

Comment: @geckels1 That is a whole different question, but in short: no, [`sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/sudo.8.html) grants you e.g. the execution rights of the owner of the executable file i.e. `root` but doesn't make you actually `root` ... Please see for example this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/150718 that might shed some light on the matter ...Please see also related to this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1411528/968501

Comment: Thank you! That is very clarifying and what I was looking for. I was pretty sure there are nuances to sudo I wasn't aware of and this shows it.