# Why micro is not recognized as text editor in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: command-line, text-editor, update-alternatives, visudo

I installed micro with `sudo apt install micro` on 22.04

I want to use visudo with micro.

`export EDITOR=micro` then next line `visudo` opens in nano.
So, then I tried `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` this also does not show micro.
(I removed vim-tiny to see if it removes it from the list)
output:

```
  Selection    Path            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano        40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed         -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano        40        manual mode
```

There is no micro but i have micro

I can run micro in the terminal by typing `micro`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> Why micro is not recognized as text editor in Ubuntu 22.04?

There appears to be no post install script included by the package maintainer to do that in the `micro` package:

```
$ apt source micro
Reading package lists... Done
NOTICE: 'micro' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
https://salsa.debian.org/go-team/packages/micro.git
Please use:
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/go-team/packages/micro.git
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 820 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe micro 2.0.9-1ubuntu0.22.04.2 (dsc) [2,664 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe micro 2.0.9-1ubuntu0.22.04.2 (tar) [812 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe micro 2.0.9-1ubuntu0.22.04.2 (diff) [5,528 B]
Fetched 820 kB in 2s (369 kB/s)  
dpkg-source: info: extracting micro in micro-2.0.9
dpkg-source: info: unpacking micro_2.0.9.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking micro_2.0.9-1ubuntu0.22.04.2.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: using patch list from debian/patches/series
dpkg-source: info: applying 01-disable-commit-hash-and-date.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying use-original-fork.patch
$
$
$ find micro-2.0.9/ -name "*postinst" -print -exec cat {} \;
$
```

Compare that to e.g. the `nano` package:

```
$ apt source nano
Reading package lists... Done
NOTICE: 'nano' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/nano.git
Please use:
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/debian/nano.git
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 1,567 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main nano 6.2-1 (dsc) [2,192 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main nano 6.2-1 (tar) [1,532 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main nano 6.2-1 (asc) [833 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main nano 6.2-1 (diff) [32.7 kB]
Fetched 1,567 kB in 2s (860 kB/s)
dpkg-source: info: extracting nano in nano-6.2
dpkg-source: info: unpacking nano_6.2.orig.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking nano_6.2-1.debian.tar.xz
$
$
$ find nano-6.2/ -name "*postinst" -print -exec cat {} \;
nano-6.2/debian/nano.postinst
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ]; then
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /bin/nano 40 \
      --slave /usr/share/man/man1/editor.1.gz editor.1.gz \
      /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pico pico /bin/nano 10 \
      --slave /usr/share/man/man1/pico.1.gz pico.1.gz \
      /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz
fi

#DEBHELPER#
nano-6.2/debian/nano-tiny.postinst
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ]; then
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /bin/nano-tiny 0 \
      --slave /usr/share/man/man1/editor.1.gz editor.1.gz \
      /usr/share/man/man1/nano-tiny.1.gz
fi

#DEBHELPER#
$
```

> How to fix this?

Set the environment variable momentarily like so:

```
sudo  EDITOR=micro visudo
```

Or add the editor to the Ubuntu alternatives system following the format:

```
update-alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>
```

like so:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/micro 40
```

so that you can later select it via:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

For additional related informative explanation see also:

[Difference between "select-editor" and "update-alternatives --config editor"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1457769)

Comment: @vanadium It is involved because the postinstall script that adds it to the alternatives system is missing for that certain version and that's the only way it can show in `update-alternatives --config editor` to be selected as an alternative ... I however checked https://salsa.debian.org/go-team/packages/micro/-/blob/debian/sid/debian/micro.postinst and they appear to have it, but not included in that version from Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

`man visudo` gives you a hint why it does not work:

```
sudo does not preserve the SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL,
or EDITOR environment variables unless they are present in
the env_keep list or the env_reset option is disabled in the
sudoers file.  The default editor path is
/usr/bin/nano:/usr/bin/vim:/usr/bin/vi which can be set at
compile time via the --with-editor configure option.
```

To make it work in a simple way, use

```
sudo EDITOR=micro visudo
```

instead.