# How do I get the brightness control working on an HP 6735s?

Tags: 13.04, brightness, hp

I can't change the brightness on my screen via hotkeys or any other method. I'm stuck with low brightness which is very hard on my eyes during long periods in front of my laptop. Is there any working solution out there?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139397&p=12621502&viewfull=1#post12621502
look at the kernel boot parameters
the file to edit is `/etc/default/grub`
after editing run `sudo update-grub` and reboot
to edit the file use 
`gksu [leafpad/gedit/mousepad/geany/scite] /etc/default/grub`
`[leafpad/gedit/mousepad/geany/scite]` is a list of names, if i wanted gedit i would do this:
`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Comment: gksudo no longer works in 13.04.

Comment: changed gksudo to gksu

Comment: Sorry but gksu and gksudo are the same (the latter points to the former). This package was leftout of 13.04 and it is recommended to run sudo in a terminal instead.

Comment: 1. `gksu` and `gksudo` are not quite the same see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/288506/107450) 2. [Why is gksu no longer installed by default in 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/284306/107450)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the xbacklight package:

```
$ Sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

You can then adjust the settings from a terminal using commands found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xbacklight.1.html).

To increase brightness by 20%:

```
$ sudo xbacklight -inc 20
```

Alternatively to decrease:

```
$ sudo xbacklight -dec 20
```

Or use the -set parameter to define the exact level:

```
$ sudo xbacklight -set 50
```

If this works for you may want to add a new startup entry so it runs on boot. Open "Startup Applications" and add the following details:

Name: Brightness

Command: xbacklight -set 60

Click add and you are done! Hope this helps.