# Gtk warning when opening Gedit in terminal

Tags: gtk, gedit

Previously, I need to clear documents history, so I Googled and found this:

http://www.watchingthenet.com/ubuntu-tip-clear-disable-recent-documents.html

I did the step, and then when I opened gedit in root terminal, I've got this:

```
root@dellph1-desktop:/# gedit

(gedit:8224): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_bookmark_file_load_from_data: assertion `length != 0' failed

(gedit:8224): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to rename file '/root/.recently-used.xbel.FP7PPV' to '/root/.recently-used.xbel': g_rename() failed: Operation not permitted

(gedit:8224): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.recently-used.xbel', but failed: Operation not permitted
root@dellph1-desktop:/#
```

And it's happpened in user terminal:

```
dellph1@dellph1-desktop:~$ gedit

(gedit:9408): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accel_label_set_accel_closure: assertion `gtk_accel_group_from_accel_closure (accel_closure) != NULL' failed
dellph1@dellph1-desktop:~$
```

I really hope someone helps in this case, thank you.

Comment: Please don't use gedit as root, it's not cool.

Comment: Previously, no problem. A warning message appeared after I used the steps suggested in the link above.
What should I do?
I've reinstall gedit, create the folder requested manually, but not solve the problem.
Finally, I Googled again and found this 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1631433  
but the thread was solved by itself, and he did not know why things happen, weird ...

Comment: @MartinOwens-doctormo- It's fine to run `gedit` as root so long as $HOME is `root`'s home.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
(nohup gedit 2>/dev/null &)
```

This runs `gedit` in the background in a sub-shell, with `nohup`. Hence, the error messages are handled by `nohup`, and closing the terminal wouldn't affect `gedit`. A simpler way would be:

```
gedit &> /dev/null
```

This just discards any error messages from `gedit`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend editing this answer to explain what this does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm recommending that you not use gedit via the root user. Try and use gedit through sudo instead.

Reinstalling gedit won't help, I believe you need to undo the damage done by following the guide.

Comment: Until now, the problem is still there. Unlike the above thread that can be solved automatically. But I am confused to make the opposite of the previously recommended procedure. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Owens: "gedit through sudo"? ..  It should be run via `gksudo` ....  and what do you mean by *"..don't use gedit as root, it's not cool*"... are you referring to "gedit" not being "cool" or running anything in Ubuntu as root is not "cool"?

Comment: gksu, sudo, pedant etc.

Comment: Not pedantic - different things. Using sudo was throwing the same warning for me which lead me to this page.   ....
_"You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as root. You should use gksudo (kdesudo on Kubuntu) to run such programs. gksudo sets HOME=/root, and copies .Xauthority to a tmp directory.This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by root."_ .....
via http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus