# Gtk-Warnings In Terminal

Tags: 11.10, command-line, gtk, gedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gtk warning when opening Gedit in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22935/gtk-warning-when-opening-gedit-in-terminal)

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed on two different machines, both using x64 installs. Only one machine returns these Gtk warnings after using `sudo gedit`. I get these warnings when opening or saving a file.

Here is an example:

`(gedit:2456): Gtk-WARNING **; Attempting to store changes into '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.KBGV9V': No such file or directory`

I also get another set of warnings related to "Attempting to set permissions of" the above mention directory.

Is this something I should be concerned with? Any way to get rid of those warnings? Like I said, my other machine doesn't return these warnings in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the warning go.....they are just that.

If you are using gedit as a superuser then I would recommend using gksudo instead

CLI=sudo

GUI=gksudo

- [Is the difference between sudo and gksu the same as the difference
  between sudo -i and sudo -s?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11825/is-the-difference-between-sudo-and-gksu-the-same-as-the-difference-between-sudo)

The reason for root permissions. See the tutorial

- http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo

Comment: Why would this happen on one machine and not the other? Same installs on both machines, with nothing installed extra.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the warning *if it hasn't gone away yet* you can create the directory(s) that are missing, as in

```
sudo mkdir -p /root/.local/share
```

Or the 1st time you delete anything as sudo it will also be created if you send to the root trash

Comment: Still fairly new to the site but how did you highlight the command in your response?

Comment: @Edubbs If you click the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/104615/edit) link under a post, you can see the source. In this particular case, code blocks have each line indented by 4 spaces and are set apart from other paragraphs by a blank line.