# What's the difference between sudo and gksudo when launching graphical applications?

Tags: gui, sudo, gksu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

It is common to see in instructions, the terminal command to edit a file:

```
sudo gedit
```

but this will be deemed inadvisable by experienced users, who instead suggest:

```
gksudo gedit
```

The question is, why the distinction and is there any harm using sudo with a graphical application?