# How to get full rights in Ubuntu to manipulate a file that is owned by root

Tags: users, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I elevate nautilus privileges to move or copy a folder as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98489/how-can-i-elevate-nautilus-privileges-to-move-or-copy-a-folder-as-root)

I want to have full rights in Ubuntu 11.10 so I don't have to use the terminal every time I want to copy and paste or edit a file that is owned by root.  Is there a way to do this?

I changed my user role to Administrator and it does not appear to have changed anything.

Is there a way, like MS Windows to simply copy/paste or edit files folders with momentary privileges to perform the task without the requirement to do it through terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is to allow file manipulations as root, but avoiding the command line, then you can launch nautilus as root. Alt+F2 followed by `gksudo nautilus` will prompt you for a password, and then launch the file manager.

You could [create a launcher](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-desktop-launchers-in-ubuntu-11-10oneiric.html) for this (disclaimer: I haven't tried the methods on that page).

Comment: Better might be `gksudo gedit` since a text editor is quite a bit simpler than a file manager, and is less likely to do dangerous things as root.  (From within nautilus, for example, you might easily accidentally try to delete `/usr`.)

Comment: A file manager is not innately more dangerous than a command line. `rm -rf / home/bar/my_dir` being the classic. I wonder if nautilus puts `/usr` into the recycle bin :) Still, I don't see much alternative if the OP wants to do all the file manipulations in a gui with root privileges.

Comment: True, though I can see accidentally striking the delete key as being a bit more common.  But that's probably a matter of opinion.  In any case, gedit shouldn't be able to recursively delete directories, so it's probably a bit safer than both other options.  :)

Comment: gedit can't do any file manipulations (beyond creating and editing) - and rightly so, it's a text editor!

Comment: Indeed.  I was not posting the comment to say your answer was wrong, only that using gedit instead is an alternative approach that may be useful as well.