# How do I open a folder as root?

Tags: nautilus, root

More specifically the

```
/etc/apt/
```

folder. I need to delete some files and replace

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

with a newer version.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To open the folder as root in the grapical file manager, run the following command:

```
gksu nautilus /etc/apt/
```

*If you wish to do your operations **from the command line**, the following command enters the intended directory and makes you root. However, you would be better off using the first method above.*

```
cd /etc/apt; sudo -i
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked fine! I used the GUI version and deleted the two (very old) backup files.

Comment: sudo -i is less typing and cleaner environmental variables http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6188826&postcount=4

Comment: I disagree with SirCharlo that first method is better than using command line. Command line is way more powerfull.

Answer (score 15):

Ubuntu 16.04 and above

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin
```

Then

```
nautilus -q
```

Open Nautilus and you'll see an option *Open as Administrator* option in the context menu of every directory.

Comment: it is work 18.04

Comment: Didn't seem to work in 18.04.2, although I see the context menu I'm unable to delete locked folders. Back to terminal I go.

Answer (score 12):

**To install Open-as-Administrator in Ubuntu open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the terminal:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install open-as-administrator
```

**After installation type this command to restart Nautilus:**

**nautilus -q**

**Reboot**

[image]

Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install -y nautilus-admin
```

Then

```
nautilus -q
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package open-as-administrator`

Comment: Doesn't work on 16.04, same mistake as @Hooli mentioned. Would love to see it working.

Answer (score 11):

Nah ! do a simple thing first. Create a custom file manager. Its easy.

Here how you can do it:

### First open gedit and paste all these:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Nautilus
Comment=Browse the filesystem with administrator rights
Exec=gksudo nautilus
Icon=file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;System;
```

Now save the file as Nautilus.desktop on your desktop.

(desktop is the file extension).

Now Open:

```
   /home/your user name/.local/share/applications
```

and cut/paste Nautilus.desktop file into there.

Now open dash and search for "Nautilus". It will open up the default file manager with root permission. Now you can navigate to any directory and delete anything you want.

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
gksudo nautilus --or -- gksu nautilus
```

or any other file explorer of your choice.

See Also [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Comment: ..it's better to launch graphical application, with root privilege, using `gksu` that `sudo`...

Answer (score 3):

In a Terminal you can use:

```
sudo -e /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Note: If you prefer to use Graphical Software you should use `gksudo` in Gnome:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or `kdesudo` in KDE:

```
kdesudo kate /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Enter your user password (not root) and you will edit file as **root**

Comment: or just sudo -e `sudo -e /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen thank you, smart option ... you are free to edit my answer for creating difference `sudo -e <YourTextEditor> /etc/apt/sources.list`