# Is it advisable to become root in Ubuntu to work with other users' files?

Tags: root, users

When I moved to Ubuntu I worked hard to get out of the habit of working as root. However, is the situation below an example of one of the few times that a user should become root?

```
 - neptune:~$ cd ../testuser/.kde/
bash: cd: ../testuser/.kde/: Permission denied
 - neptune:~$ sudo cd ../testuser/.kde/
sudo: cd: command not found
```

Note that I do happen to have the password for `testuser`, however I feel that working as root is preferable to `su`ing to `testuser`.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Upon researching solutions I see that my best course of action is to just `su` to the user whose files I intend to start scripting on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124023/how-do-i-open-a-folder-as-root) helpful. Consider placing shared files in common directories with appropriate permissions so that multiple users can work on them.

Comment: Thank you Wolverine. In fact, that thread was rather informative but it only shows how to become root (-i -e), not how to avoid becoming root.

Comment: Upon researching solutions I see that my best course of action is to just su to the user whose files I intend to start scripting on. Thanks.