# How to remove files with no permission

Tags: files, delete

I have leftovers of [PyLotRO](https://launchpad.net/pylotro), a Windows emulator, but I can't move all files to the trash bin.

How do I change permissions and delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine where the folder is and change the permissions using [`chmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder/foldername
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example if  the folder was called `BLAH` and was located at `/home/user` then you would type

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/BLAH
```

That should change the permissions for the folder and all its files and sub directories to read/write/execute. Then you should be able to delete them. Also be aware that Linux is case sensitive so you do have to use a capital `-R` in the line and if your directory has caps you have to  use caps the exact same way it show or it will fail

Since you said you can find the folder in terminal you can use this command

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/folder/foldername
```

That will delete the folder and its subdirectories as root.

It will ask you for a password and when you type it in it will look like nothing is happening . It doesn't show any indication that you are typing it in. Just type the password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will delete the files for you.

Comment: Didn't work says cant find file or carpet/directory

Comment: well you have to use the path to your directory .. i dont know what that is so i put an example as to how to do it.

Comment: It worked, after trying chmod -r 777 while on file (clicked to see file location on terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Having all permissions as a root, you should use:

```
sudo -i
```

And for completely removing files or folders and their contents, you can use:

```
rm
```

For obtaining more information about these commands (and other commands!) you can use:

```
man
```

For example,

```
man rm
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to use your GUI file manager (nautilus, thunar, caja, dolphin, etc) you could use the "root account" to delete the files.

Most file managers probably have an "Open Folder as Root" or similar option, or just run the file manager with `sudo` (, from a terminal would work.

For thunar: `sudo thunar`. Or for nautilus: `sudo nautilus` , etc

If you're using nautilus, the answers here should help: [How do I open a folder as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124023/how-do-i-open-a-folder-as-root)

Then browse to the offending files and delete them.

In a terminal, just `sudo rm` should work too

Comment: Doesnt work for me, no option for root access. I can put the file location in the terminal though any use?

Comment: What happens when you open a terminal and type `sudo nautilus` ? That should open nautilus with root permissions. Then you can go to the folder containing those files and delete them.