# difference between gksudo and sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo, gksu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

I have tiny script that I want it to run on start-up, but it needs sudo privileges so I use gksudo for the job. but it fails. (it works correctly using sudo.)
Is there any difference between sudo and gksudo beside the inteface?

BTW: this is the tiny script I mentioned:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight|if read state; then \
    echo $((1-$state)) | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight; fi;
```

Comment: As you might have guessed, I'm total newbie!

Comment: See this question http://askubuntu.com/q/11760/61218

Comment: Thank you. I've seen it. But I don't see how $HOME parameter affects my code.

Comment: @fossfreedom I don't think this is an exact duplicate: *this* question has an issue similar to mine: my script fails with gksudo, but works with sudo, whereas the other does not involve scripts.  I am not a *total* newbie, but I don't see how my script is affected by anything discussed in the other question.

Comment: comment by user azernik in invalid answer below should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 40):

The main difference is as follows :

`gksudo` : is used to run graphical (GUI) applications as root
`sudo`   : is used to run command line applications as root

The reason your script won't work with `gksudo` is because you can't run a GUI without X running.

Comment: And why? I'm a typical dumb user and saw that typing "sudo" is just enough to run even graphical applications with root rights. So I use sudo and save two letters of typing. Except if you can convince me why I should type two more letters ;)

Comment: Because the answer is wrong. gksudo is used to pop up the password prompt in a GUI window, no matter whether the application is GUI or CLI. sudo, similarly, asks for the password at the terminal instead of in a GUI window, regardless of the type of application being run. Sometimes, in scripts that don't run in an interactive terminal, gksu is the easiest way to get a user-entered password straight to sudo.

Comment: why so many votes on a wrong answer....

Comment: because down-vote costs reputation :)

Comment: xenial was last LTS with the gksu package containing gksudo and gksu. For historical interest, one thing I think it _may_ have done differently is not to change certain gui/gnome files in places like `~/.gtk3` to root ownership.