# I cannot delete files from root's Trash

Tags: sudo, trash, rm

I deleted some large files from nautilus launched as sudo.  They still show in `/home/.Trash-0/files/<foldername>`
when I type `sudo sh -c "du -h /home | grep -P '[0-9]G\t'"` but when I type `sudo rm /home/.Trash-0/files/*` I get the message:

```
rm: cannot remove `/home/.Trash-0/files/*': No such file or directory
```

I was able to delete individual files with their exact file names in place of *, but when I used  *, it gave the error message as above.  I do not want to have to delete them all individually if I can help it.

Answer (score 4):

[Taken from [**Thread:** I can't empty the trash as a user](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4800640&postcount=3)]

(Solution posted works in Ubuntu 13.10.)

> The Trash folder is a hidden folder(the folders name begins with a
>   period) in your home directory. You can press Ctrl+H in nautilus or
>   select Show Hidden Folder from the View menu to list the hidden
>   folders.
>
> You can open nautilus in the .Trash folder:
>
> `gksu nautilus ~/.Trash`
>
> in Hardy Heron the Trash is in ~/.local/share/Trash/files/
>
> `gksu nautilus ~/.local/share/Trash/files/`

*Select the items you want to delete in the folder.*

**OR**

> You can delete the content of the folder from the terminal:
>
> `sudo rm -fr ~/.Trash/*`
>
> Hardy Heron:
>
> `sudo rm -fr ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*`

Answer (score 3):

**Fixed it now by:**

`sudo -i` to get into the root account, and then `cd to /home/.Trash-0/info`. Then `rm -rf *`. Then `cd ../files/`. Then `rm -rf *` again. Appears to have worked.

Comment: Directory doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Do `gksu nautilus` to launch nautilus with root permissions. After that, go to the files you need to delete. Right click on them and change the permissions so that all users have access to edit and delete them. After that, you can just delete them as you regularly would without root permissions.

Comment: Running Nautilus with plain `sudo` is not recommended.

Comment: I guess so but it works for me.

Comment: Oh it works.. sorta. It causes problems later. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus