# Not able to save files

Tags: permissions, www

I had installed apache,php just now and for checking whether php executes i had opened /var/ww and edited index.html file , but i was unable to save the file. It says i do have the proper permissions to save the file. I had logged in as administrator. I had right clicked the index.html and i was unable to edit permissions it says i am not the owner.

What to do with this?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try on your console to edit the file with `sudo`?

```
sudo gedit index.html
```

That should work.

Comment: Graphical applications should not be run directly with `sudo`; [a frontend like `gksu`/`gksudo` should be used instead.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Terminal go to the specified directory and try running the following command to edit the file:

```
gksudo gedit index.html
```

The `gksudo` command will give you root permission so you will probably be able to edit the file.

Note that I used `gedit` in the command, because gedit is the default text editor in Ubuntu, but if you are using a Ubuntu variant this text editor is not installed by default.
If you're using a variant use `nano` (command line text editor) instead of `gedit`, to save the changes press Ctrl + O and then Ctrl + X to exit the text editor.