# Moving folder to trash

Tags: 12.04, lts

How can I give myself permission to delete a folder from "file system/opt"? Folder owner is root. I am the only user of this computer but I did not install the OS. I am not much of a tech person but can follow instructions.

Answer (score 1):

First: do you really need to delete it?

Second: I would not recommend to use sudo. Instead I think it's better to always use gksudo. Why?:

> You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as
>   root. You should use gksudo (kdesudo on Kubuntu) to run such programs.
>   gksudo sets HOME=~root, and copies .Xauthority to a tmp directory.
>   This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by root.

More info: [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

You can open a terminal,and type:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Press Enter and a new window will open. Now you can delete anything, included things that you should not delete!

Comment: The information mentioned is true and correct (Instead of sudo using gksudo)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
sudo chown <username>:<username> /opt
```

but I probably will cause the system to not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

it is not recommended to give yourself a permissions on the opt folder, this sometimes cause a security problems, so if you want to edit a file in the folder just run:

```
sudo nautilus
```

and edit the file ! :)
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue the following in Terminal:

`sudo rm /opt/name-of_folder_or_file`

will immediately delete the named file or folder. Exercise this command with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Press ALT-F2, then type: `sudo rm -rv /opt/INSERT-FOLDERNAME-HERE`

---

This only works if you have sudo permission. (You must be an Administrator user)