# how to change permission of user using GUI

Tags: permissions

been using linux/ubuntu for a while, and been always annoyed as to why i cannot create folders, overwrite files and stuff using GUI(desktop). but i can however, manipulate the files using sudo CLI.

ive been always interacting with the files through gui, how can i change this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to run the file manage using `gksudo`, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)  for details as to why you should use `gksudo`

For example, if you're interested in running nautilus, you need to use:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Although this does require opening a terminal, I tend to use XFCE so have a shortcut to use for running commands (`Alt+F2`) I can't remember if Unity has a similar shortcut.

You should be more than careful when using a file browser as root however, because of the possible damage you can cause. I'd recommend not doing it