# Cannot login to ubuntu after startx command

Tags: login, xserver

I wanted to manually configure the internet settings & decided to seek help from [this website.](http://afrodita.rcub.bg.ac.rs/~ivica/nlm/part1/netaccess.html) Ubuntu did not allow me to perform **step 1** saying,

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting
```

so I logged in as superuser by executing `sudo -s`. Then I executed **step 1**. Suddenly all the tray icons disappeared & the only thing that was being displayed was the wallpaper. I wasn't able to shutdown/restart & chose to shutdown the laptop directly with power button. Upon restart, I had the following problems,

**PROBLEMS :**

- I am able to login with a guest account.
- I'm unable to login with my user account. Logging in brings me back to the login screen.

I am using ubuntu 13.04. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### To solve the problem:

Open a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type in the commands:

```
cd ~
sudo chown username:groupname .Xauthority
```

*(replace username and groupname with that of your own, usually your group name will be same as your username.)*

#### Avoid running `startx` as root:

Since you started X system as root *(by logging-in as root and using `startx`)* the file `.Xauthority` in your user-home directory (`~`) got owned by the *root*, and that's the reason why you're stuck with log-in loops. And that's why you shouldn't run `sudo startx`. You can solve this by giving the ownership of the file back to your user as shown above.

#### Reference:

- [`sudo` Vs. `gksu`/`gksudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus/11766#11766)

Comment: When I try this, it says: "sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted"

Comment: @gartenriese please try these commands: `find /home/username -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir sudo chown username:username {} +` and `find /home/username -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir sudo chown username:username {} +` from a `tty` or from recovery mode as `root` after mounting the `/` with RW permissions with `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but it worked when I tried it in the terminal that opens when you press ctrl+alt+F1. Thanks though!

Comment: I foolishly ran sudo startx on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to see what would happen and I couldn't log in. I logged onto a different user and I tried changing ownship of .Xauthority, I tried removing .Xauthority and nothing worked.  I removed the .Xauthority file again and tried the two find commands to change ownership of all files and directories in home, and it worked. Thanks for that solution, nice job!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add something to precise's answer. I did exactly that but it wasn't enough in my case. If someone still can't log in after following precise's instructions, do this:

```
ls -l ~/.ICEauthority
```

If it says something like `-rw------- 1 root root 684 may  9 11:56 /home/user/.ICEauthority`, do

```
sudo chown user:user ~/.ICEauthority
```

where `user` is, of course, your username.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and tried multiple different ways to try and fix the problem. This is what best worked for me.

- Press ctrl alt f1
- Then login.
- Type in

mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak

Sometimes, it may say that there is no such file or directory. DO NOT WORRY. Just move on to the next steps.

type in **exit**.

press ctrl alt f7 then try longing again.

Hope that helps!