# Find out my user's group name without a terminal

Tags: command-line, permissions, xorg, login

I have managed to break my X server, and am trying to attempt the solution offered in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407720/cannot-login-to-ubuntu-after-startx-command) page. I only have one user on the system, but I have no idea what its group name is, which means I can't execute the solution offered on the page.

Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F(x) just brings up a flashing white cursor, but I can't type anything. I only have Ctrl+Alt+F7 at my disposal, but unable to login and bring up a prompt with Ctrl+Alt+T.

The only access I have to a shell of any description seems to be by booting into recovery mode and dropping to the shell. However, I then don't get any response from the shell when I type `users` (as suggested by this page as a way to find out my groupname).

A valid answer to this question would either:

a) Allow me to find out the groupname so that I can execute the `sudo chown username:groupname .Xauthority` command, or

b) Provide an alternative way to fix the XServer issue, which sounds very similar to the one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407720/cannot-login-to-ubuntu-after-startx-command).

Comment: If you can't get a shell in any of those ways, you've mucked up more than X... what did you actually do?

Comment: Yeah, I did wonder! I've never been able to access more than the Ctrl+Alt+F7 desktop, but no idea why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought usually when creating a new user (during installation too), Ubuntu creates a usergroup with exactly the same name as the username. So for example my username is `bytecommander` and therefore I'm also (the only) member of the group `bytecommander`.

I hope this helps you. Please don't forget to accept the best answer to your problem or to give votes to improve the answerer's reputation (and yours, by accepting)...

Comment: That should work - or you could get the primary group name from the username using the `id` command i.e. `id -gn username`

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you can't get a working shell from your system, you may need to boot into the installation media (CD, USB) & get a terminal from there.

If you mount your /home drive - you can do this from the desktop - then you can open a terminal, and get typing:

`sudo -i
mount # This will show your drive as /dev/sda1 or similar
cd /media/ubuntu/sda1/home/you/ # or whatever it was, to get to your home directory..
chown you:you .Xauthority`

In fact taking ownership of the whole directory might be useful, as `chown -R you:you *`

`reboot`

remove CD etc, & we're done. Unless I'm right & there's more :) - if you can't get a shell on your system there may well be.