# Ubuntu 14.04 log-in fails, in VirtualBox, seems to be a libGL problem

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, xorg

Just installed 14.04.2 LTS i386 as a VirtualBox VM, on a Windows 7 host with AMD 64 processor.

Then, I could not log in normally. It accepts my username & pswd, thinks a while, then resets the greeting screen. I can log in via tty (ctrl-alt-F1).

Installed guest additions successfully from tty session. Restarted, the screen size is now larger, showing that guest additions are effective (at least partially). But I still cannot log in at the desktop.

In my home dir, file .xsession-errors starts with these lines:

```
> libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
> libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
> libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
```

So libGL can't find dri or dri2, and fails to load the vboxvideo driver. Surely this was a failure during ubuntu installation, right? In /var/log I checked three vbox additions log files and found no errors. But Xorg.0.log has this:

```
> AIGLX error: vboxvideo does not support required DRI extension
> AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
> AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
> GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
> VBoxVideo(0): Setting screen physical size to 277 x 182
```

So, is my virtual machine insufficient to support the Ubuntu Unity interface, is that the problem? Or is it maybe something else?

Would best step be to just start over, installing linux into a new VM with increased base memory and video memory?

Thank you!

-- Peter

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem after I run startx while I had root permissions.

I solved the problem looking at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407720/cannot-login-to-ubuntu-after-startx-command)

Basically you do

cd ~

and then

sudo chown username:groupname .Xauthority

where username and groupname has to be changed accordingly