# Could not access desktop after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded my system from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04.But then i can't access my desktop, only mouse pointer is visible no unity bar . Then i restarted the computer and log in as guest. it is worked.
What happened to my system ? How can I access my desktop ? PLs Help

Comment: Can you reboot again and try to access your main account?

Comment: I can reboot and login to main account but nothing worked then .only blank desktop with wallpaper and mouse pointer which can move freely.no right button functions .. nothing

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors?

Comment: Grub > Advanced Options > Revover Mode > Root > `mount -a -o remount,rw /` > Creat a new Admin account

Comment: I am afraid we are going to have to close this as a bug and tell you to file a bug report.

Comment: i am having this same problem. Things were fine with Ubuntu 13.10 on dual monitor. No graphics problem were there. please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ownership of .Xauthority transferred to root](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436925/ownership-of-xauthority-transferred-to-root)

Answer (score -1):

After looking for different alternatives, I finally found the solution. Try this, it worked for me: 
http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/10/how-to-fix-login-issues-on-ubuntu-1110.html

1. At login screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to console mode.
2. Use your username and password to login.
3. Enter now these commands:

   ls -Shla | grep “Xauthority”

   sudo mv .Xauthority Xauthority.old

   sudo shutdown -r now

Comment: It is better to summarize the important points than to just provide a link, as that link may not always be available.