# Running incorrect command

Tags: login

Please help me.

i have Ubuntu 12.04.

I ran this command sudo apt-get update -f and canceled  terminal window  during running .
when i restarted Ubuntu ,Ubuntu did not login in.I typed correct password but it goes back to login screen again and again.

Please help me

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/436925/269282 . BTW, the title of your question is not very suggestive...

Answer (score -1):

Try rebooting into recovery mode and select "Root".  From there, reinstall 'gdm'.

```
apt-get -f install gdm
```

then just reboot.  You should see a login window

Comment: unable to purse or open.

Comment: Why GDM? 12.04 uses LightDM.

Comment: ubuntu-gnome-desktop uses gdm which is an optional package but so is lightdm for ubuntu-desktop.  I am expecting to give "apt-get -f" a chance to do its "incomplete" stuff so gdm or lightdm doesn't matter much if he has a broken system.

Comment: the PACKAGE LISTs or status file could not be parsed or opened

Comment: In that case, take a look here /var/log/apt/history.log.  You will need to login back to Recovery Mode by selecting "Root".  From the history.log file, see which package was getting installed when you closed the window - it should be a package name towards end.  Do a "apt-get remove" and "apt-get autoremove" right after.  This is to get back to the state hopefully your system was before this problem.

Comment: IT was not installing ,it was removing packages.

Comment: The point is 'reverse' the whatever operation using 'apt-get' to get back to previous and hopefully working state. Let know if you try it.  Theoretically, it should work.  Though, I am surprised that there is no 'undo' kind of operation supported by 'apt-get'.  I have used 'yum' extensively and it had this 'undo' transaction support for exactly scenarios like this.