# Cannot login to my main user. Maybe stuck in some kind of a loop or hit some error

Tags: logs

I have ubuntu 18.04.
The problem is that i cannot login to my main user account, when i enter my password, it shows a blank black screen with only the mouse cursor and the processor starts making sound.

Because i needed to use my computer, i have now created a new user with all the root priviledge.

**Is there anyway i can view the log of what is causing the problem?**

A little bit of background is that :

While the system was all fine, i was trying to install some japanese language keyboard. My bad, that I did not kept track of what commands i was running. That is when this all started.

Comment: First and foremost, [clean your `xauthority`](https://askubuntu.com/a/436927/212930) file, and try again. If this doesn't work, then we can move on from there ;)

Comment: The most likely place where the problem will be logged is the original user's `~/.xsession-errors` file ex. `tail /home/olduser/.xsession-errors`