# copy+paste problem from root to partition folder

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, nautilus, permissions

I am trying to copy some folders from my portable hard drive to one of the partitions. The paste button is not working in the destination folder and whenever I am trying a drag-drop with my mouse, it says that I don't have permission to create there, albeit I have the root. Even the new folder button is not working.

So, I'm now performing this copy paste action by opening a terminal and running `gksudo nautilus` but its a one time option.
If I further want to copy paste, again i need to open terminal and type the code. I dont want to do that every time.Is there any permanent option/process?

Comment: what is the location of the destination folder?

Comment: I hope you know you can do the same thing using Alt + f2 without having to open a terminal.

Comment: Will you also define which partition type your portable hard drive have. Some time it happens it. Remove your portable drive and plug it again. make sure it does not have lock folder in your portable drive. it's also happen with root user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other way. In order to change files in the `root` folder, you need to be root. In most GNU/Linux distros (including Ubuntu), programs execute as a standard user by default, even if you are the administrator on your system. In order to get a program to execute as root, you need to type in `gksudo nautilus`, which is exactly what you did. However, I suppose if you want to simplify the process you could write an executable script.

Answer (score 0):

open nautilus with sudo

sudo nautilus

and then perform all the transfer

Hope this works

Comment: It is [better to open graphical applications with `gksudo` than with `sudo`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus).

Answer (score 0):

To copy stuff from the root drive you will likely need to use a root session for your file manager, just open a terminal window, and type in "sudo nautilus" without the quotes then your password, just be careful as that makes everything rw, including system files.