# receiving "command not found" error messages after fresh reinstall of Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, 14.04, lubuntu

Lubuntu 14.04 was working really great. . .until I messed up and had to do a complete fresh reinstall.

Now I receive error messages when I input commands into the Terminal, even after immediately completing the fresh install.

For example I type:

```
sudo leafpad ‬/etc/default/
```

or `sudo leafpad ‬/etc/default/grub`

I get:

```
sudo: leafpad: command not found
```

I type:

```
sudo update-initramfs ‬-u
```

or `sudo update-grub`

I get:

```
sudo: update-initramfs: command not found
```

or `sudo: update-grub: command not found`

If I use the command `mkdir` I get:

```
mkdir: command not found
```

I also get this same exact error message, command not found, with `sudo apt-get` and `wget`

In other words I can't do anything that I was able to do when inputting commands into the terminal.

So I cannot add any repositories or update anything at all. I am not really sure what is causing the problem(s).

It appeared to me that Lubuntu installed and booted up OK. However just as soon as I enter anything into the Terminal I immediately get the above error messages. I have tried to do the reinstall three times, same error messages.

If anyone can suggest any fixes I would really appreciate it very much. Thank you!

Comment: First thing you "You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as root. You should use gksudo (or gksu)" -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $PATH` tho your question.

Comment: Apparently the problem may be in the installation process. I wish Lubuntu would just have a pre-made CD. I am going to re-download and re-burn to disc. If that doesn't work then I will add the output, if possible. Unfortunately neither qksudo or qksu worked nor did echo $PATH. All three showed an error message with "command not found".

Comment: Check the [MD5Sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) after download.