# Error formatting SD card

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, gparted, sd-card

I'm now trying to resize a 64 Gb SD card and format it to ext4 (i use a normal SD card reader, not a usb card reader) in order to use it on my android device. formating it to fat32 won't give me a problem, my problems start if I format it to ext4, then the SD card would show errors

[image]
[image]

The SD card error that I see, is `permission denied` I cannot include a screenshot because I formated it and it ain't happening now but I can  show you this screenshot, the sd card is formated to `ext4` using gparted

[image]

It clearly shows that cannot write anything to the SD, as a regular user, I have to be root.

**Edit** after following **sмurf**'s answer, I see

[image]

edit 2, gksudo solves few issues but when formating to ext4 I still see

[image]

Comment: First: Don't run graphical applications with sudo! Second: Your question is not clear. Are you getting this error when you try to format fat32 or ext4? You say ext4, but why would you use Windows to format it fat32 then? Third: What is the *exact* error?

Comment: @Seth first Gparted won't start unless I open a terminal and type `sudo gparted` I'll include a screenshot in a minute. Second I get this error when I format it to ext4, I would use windows to format it to fat when that happens, because when I get the error, I can't use the sd anymore. Third, I'll include a screenshot in a minute

Comment: @Seth question edited, I'm going to be leaving the computer for few hours, hopefully the question is clear now, if not, please ask me anything and I will respond as soon as I come back to askubuntu in few hours

Comment: Without sudo: use a gparted live dvd :+

Comment: @Rinzwind would I be able to use it on android or as swurf says, i would have a problem? - the point is not only to format it but to be able to use it on android

Comment: Looks like you are getting a little confused by what I meant with "don't run it as sudo". Read this http://askubuntu.com/a/11766/107450

Comment: @Seth you have the correct answer for gksudo instead of sudo, however I still see problems, I changed the title of the question since it might be unrelated  to running gparted as root

Comment: My sudo point was secondary, yes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: You can not run gparted without sudo.

Your *real* problem however appears to be that an SD card formatted in Linux is unusable in an Android device because of a permission issue. You should be able to fix that by making the root directory of the card world writeable:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/<YOUR_SDCARD_DEVICE>
sudo mount /dev/<YOUR_SDCARD_DEVICE> /mnt
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/.
sudo umount /mnt
```

Note: I haven't really tested that.

Comment: please  read my edit