# How do i solve the error problem while running ' sudo nautilus ' in kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: nautilus, kubuntu

When I run command `$ sudo nautilus`, I am getting the following error message:

```
** (nautilus:2611): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-JjKUQBOPpS: Connection refused
(nautilus:2611): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
(nautilus:2611): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/nit/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: Try `gksudo nautilus`. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus

Comment: Try `sudo open nautilus`?

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu doesn't use Nautilus as its file manager but uses Dolphin instead. Therefore,

```
sudo nautilus
```

OR

```
gksudo nautilus
```

gives error.

Please, type

```
sudo dolphin
```

OR

```
gksudo dolphin
```

to get root privileges for your file manager.

Answer (score 0):

[**Do not use `sudo` directly with graphical programs.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Try either:

```
gksudo nautilus
# or
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus
```

You'll probably need to install `gksudo` first, if you're going by the first method:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```