# Boot Clonezilla ISO from GRUB2 Menu

Tags: grub2, 14.04, clonezilla

I want to use the most current Clonezilla iso file to backup the partition that contains the Ubuntu operating system that is stored on partition one of my computer's hard drive and I want to be able to boot the iso file from the Grub2 menu.

How would I set this up?

Answer (score 2):

1. Put Clonezilla ISO file in root `/` directory.
2. Open the terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
   ```
3. Insert the following text at the end of the file:

   ```
   menuentry "Clonezilla Live" {
    set isofile="/clonezilla-live-2.2.3-10-amd64.iso"
   loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
   linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live live-config nolocales edd=on nomodeset
   ocs_live_run=\"ocs-live-general\" ocs_live_extra_param=\"\"   ocs_live_keymap=\"\" ocs_live_batch=\"no\" ocs_lang=\"\" vga=788   ip=frommedia nosplash toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile
   initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
   }
   ```
4. Save file, exit and open GRUB's config file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

Comment out the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` so it looks like:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Make sure that the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT=[some number]` has a number >0, for example, 10

5. Save file and exit and run

   ```
   sudo update-grub2
   ```

---

ADDITIONAL NOTES:

⠀- `/clonezilla-live-2.2.3.10-amd64.iso` -- change the name of iso file to match the one you have.

⠀- `(hd0,1)` may be different for you depending on how you installed Ubuntu.

> (hdX,Y)  X = hard drive #, Y = partition.

⠀You can also see my YouTube video for the above procedure: [Boot Clonezilla ISO from Grub2 Menu](http://youtu.be/WD1JyzIcejk).

Comment: Regarding your YouTube video take a look at: [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus). The same applies to opening gedit as root. I hope this helps the next time you make another video to upload to YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution provided by [JJ Avila](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489752/boot-clonezilla-iso-from-grub2-menu#490206) but modification in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` didn't worked for me. 
This what i've done.

1. Copy clonezilla iso to / (root) directory

   `sudo cp /path/to/your_clonezilla_iso /`
2. Run `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

**EDIT:**

```
menuentry "Clonezilla live" {
set isofile="/clonezilla-live-20160503-xenial-i386.iso"
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap nolocales edd=on nomodeset nodmraid ocs_live_run=\"ocs-live-general\" ocs_live_extra_param=\"\" keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_batch=\"no\" locales= vga=788 ip=frommedia nosplash toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile
initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

save & exit.

3. Run `sudo update-grub2`

**NOTE:** iso in root directory that's why

```
set isofile="/clonezilla-live-20160503-xenial-i386.iso"
```

**(Here change name of your iso)**

**REFERENCE: [Clonezilla Live on Hard Drive](http://clonezilla.org/livehd.php)**

Comment: Don't post your Q as an A. Clonezilla ISO structure was modified. It seems like they are using isohybrid now. I suspect that reference is outdated now.

Comment: Though, here is [the thread from SystemRescueCD on HybridISO](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=9702&sid=4c127cec87df07604f70ddd801b9d519#p9702) that might be relevant.

Comment: @mlt: To me it looks like Lnux wanted to post their own version of a working answer since the existing one didn't work for them.

Comment: I believe David is correct.

Comment: This worked for me. The other answer did not.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Great to hear :)

Comment: @mlt This is not a question. The reference is not outdated and i already post the essential parts of it in answer.

Comment: Who voted to delete this post? Any specific reason?