# Boot clonezilla from hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, iso, clonezilla

I mean to boot clonezilla from HD.
I find [official information](https://clonezilla.org/livehd.php) confusing/incomplete.

First it explains how to boot from files obtained by decompressing `clonezilla-live-x.x.x-x-amd64.zip` (current stable version is 2.8.1-12).

Then it states "from Clonezilla live >= 2.6.2-15, you can use only the Clonezilal live iso file in grub2."
So I wonder:

1. If that is actually true, what is the use of `clonezilla-live-x.x.x-x-amd64.zip` for later versions?
2. Can anyone confirm if the zip-method for >= 2.6.2-15 does not work?

Then it shows the grub2 menu entry for iso booting

```
menuentry "clonezilla-live" {
    ISO="/clonezilla-live-2.7.2-39-amd64.iso"
    search --set -f $ISO
    loopback loop $ISO
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" vga=791 ip= net.ifnames=0 splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1 findiso=$ISO
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

3. How will grub2 be able to tell in which partition to look for the iso image?
   Or, how will I know which is the correct partition to place the iso image?
   It doesn't have a line like  `set root=(hd0,4)`. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/880484/226614) shows a very similar entry, but adding a partition. Same [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/490206/226614). But [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/769659/226614) does not.

**Related**:

1. [Boot Clonezilla ISO from GRUB2 Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489752/boot-clonezilla-iso-from-grub2-menu)
2. [Adding Clonezilla to GRUB boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880470/adding-clonezilla-to-grub-boot-menu)

Comment: out of my league, I only use a live usb CZ boot.. I really do appreciate this app though. the zip might be for manual unarchiving and extraction of single files.. something CZ does not do on it's own (unfortunate as Acronis True Image did it easy back in my Windoze days)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find you answer in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413776/make-grub-boot-entry-to-load-recovery-menu).
It's about getting **a recovery partition** to work **with a new grub menu entry**.
The solution I found to do it, was Clonezilla and I was able to make it run on this drive configuration:

```
nvme0n1                259:0    0 119.2G  0 disk   
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0  26.1G  0 part                recovery (with Clonezilla)
├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0  87.9G  0 part   /            lubuntu system drive
└─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0   5.3G  0 part   /boot/efi    efi-boot
```

I save my images from nvme0n1p2 on my raid set.