# How to disable - Lubuntu's graphical grub theme

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, themes

I use Lubuntu 22.04 LTS on my computer, and am testing grub editing.

It seems Lubuntu is using some kind of graphical interface to show grub.
[image]

Can I disable it to use the same as Ubuntu's default?

Here's is my grub config file : **cat /etc/default/grub**

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

These are the results of **update-grub**

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/lubuntu-grub-theme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda4@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

I can see it pointing thos two files:
`/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg'
/usr/share/grub/themes/lubuntu-grub-theme/theme.txt

Should the solution be to delete the **/usr/share/grub/themes/lubuntu-grub-theme/theme.txt** so it doesn't load it ? Will this work ?

Comment: You haven't provided release details; but you could just remove the Lubuntu theme for your *unstated* release.  FYI:  The Lubuntu theme only shows if your hardware is capable of showing it; if booted on other hardware (*where it can't show*) it's identical to Ubuntu's anyway.   (fyi: theme used by lubuntu is found in package `lubuntu-grub-theme`)

Comment: @mook765 my comment was made ~11 hours ago, yet the 22.04 was only added 8 hours ago...   I left the comment alone (ie. *didn't delete it*) as it's referred to in the OP's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

I've been able to remove the theme by removing the packet with:

`apt purge lubuntu-grub-theme`.

I had to `update-grub`, otherwise I got this a message before the grub menu:

`/usr/share/grub/themes/lubuntu-grub-theme/theme.txt` not found

*I confirm the answer from @guiverc and I added the release version like he/she suggested.*

Comment: Well done for solving it... I didn't *actually* provide an answer, just my thoughts (*via quick comment*). I personally like Lubuntu's theme (*on boxes where it shows*) and would have likely replaced it with another, `update-initramfs` & `update-grub` etc **or** done as @mook765 suggested... but well done for achieving what you wanted, and thanks for sharing it so as to benefit others too.

Comment: Also be aware you've potentially left a *minefield* for yourself; so don't trip over it later.  ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/lubuntu-desktop shows a *depends* rule on `lubuntu-grub-theme` , so leaving it installed & just using another theme OR using no-theme makes more sense to me (*fewer minefields the better for release-upgrade time, or should you need disk space into the future etc*)

Comment: I'm using Cinnamon desktop. So I presume there are no worries about Lubuntu itself. It's just a better base to me for Cinnamon as the standard Ubuntu, that gives me trouble with the networking and Bluetooth applets, and some icon packs on Cinnamon. I could resolve them, but very inconvenient on every reinstall. What's not the case with Lubuntu, or Ubuntu Mate as a base. Lubuntu was faster to install, so there's is my choice. @guiverc

Comment: I like the theme too. But when I'll have to learn how the grub works, it makes it just more complicate to me with these theme settings. So I leave it without for the time I need to master the basic grub options. We'll see later for the theme.  @guiverc

Comment: I would like you to look to the results of my testing of the grub here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413776/make-grub-boot-entry-to-load-dd-recovery-menu Because I have an issue with an entry that creates a double. I tough the theme could cause it, but it's not. @guiverc

Answer (score 5):

The appearance of grub is managed by `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`. Remove the executable bit from this file with `sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`

Create the file `/etc/grub.d/04_set-colors` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Set the colors of the boot-menu. Available colors are

#    black
#    blue
#    green
#    cyan
#    red
#    magenta
#    brown
#    light-gray
#    dark-gray
#    light-blue
#    light-green
#    light-cyan
#    light-red
#    light-magenta
#    yellow
#    white

echo "${1}set menu_color_normal=white/black"
echo "${1}set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray"
```

Make the file executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/04_set-colors`

Finally run `sudo update-grub`.

This will give you a very basic grub menu with black background and text- and hilight-colors of your choice.

You can easily undo the changes by removing the newly created file `/etc/grub.d/04_set-colors`, giving the executable bit back to `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme` and, of course, running `sudo update-grub` again.

Comment: I like the idea of editing this configuration, but I need to master editing the grub itself first.
My question was rather to disable it as to edit it. Thanks for the suggestion @mook765

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have been dealing with this.  I am running 22.04.3 LTS.  I found that all you need to do is comment out the line in `/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg` then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

The following commands will comment out all the lines in the `/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg`, then update the grub.

```
sudo sed -i 's/^/# /' /etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg
sudo update-grub
reboot
```