Grub menu advanced options entries are cut off
My default Kernel is not working anymore with my graphic hardware. But I can succeed with an older Kernel from advanced options. Unfortunately the entries for older Kernels all look the same, so I cannot differentiate between a normal and recovery mode as only a limited number of characters are displayed for the entries nor can I read the full version number of the kernel. I don't want to start my system in recovery mode.
Is there a way to change grub settings get more text space to see the entire Kernel option entries or use a smaller font and/or get rid of the small scrollable selection window with its character limitationsand use full screen (currently Grub is running with a Lubuntu theme that just has a small scrollable text window in the middle)?
Is there a text-only simple mode for grub2?

Grub is only text. Boot in recovery and jot down the location of the kernel info and then when you reboot you can scroll down that number of lines and make the selection. Grub comes up before the OS so how is it using a theme?

This is for version 22.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414369/how-to-disable-lubuntus-graphical-grub-theme the lat solution may be right for you but check the files in grub if you have another version

You can change the GRUB settings for sure, but I'm sure what would be a quicker solution is to just select the entry you would like more information on with the arrow keys and then press "e" to edit the boot entry. Hit Escape to go back to the menu.

How grub appears is very dependent on your machine firmware/hardware, as the same settings on different hardware will look very different.   Grub runs before the Linux OS actually has started (ie. it's a bootloader), thus how it appears is very machine specific. You can change theme as wxl already stated, but you've not provided any release details so we don't yet know what grub version etc; as its helpful if you tell us so we provide accurate advice for your unstated Lubuntu release.

@David FYI:  Lubuntu uses a theme (by default), though not all devices will show/use that theme, meaning it will appear as pure text for some hardware anyway. The Lubuntu theme (if machine can use it) does make text larger (and easier to read, esp. for older folks like me) but I have seen some setups where parts of the lines are too long to appear (800x480|600 vga for example) as lines don't scroll & the kernel versions don't fit on screen...

Thanks @guiverc since the OP has given none of that info who knows. When I installed Lubuntu I got the standard text grub display.

the point was, when I use the advaned options to select the kernel all kernels read the same and the entry is tpo long for the fontsize and cropped and I cannot distinguish between recovery mode and normal launch of these kernels (from which I cannot read the whole numbers). I would prefer an Asciii mode of Grub where I can read all the entries. The background was that I needed to launch an older kernel as the more reent ones led to a black screen.

Have you tried amending or just removing (moving) /etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg then update-grub or ANSWERs already provided (they look pretty good for me; though I still don't have release details which are key to ensure solutions are appropriate for your box; given you know your release adjust what has been provided).  Lubuntu has used 3 different themes of late & I don't know which release/setup you're using..
