# how to delete locked folders/files

Tags: files, directory, delete

How to delete locked folders/files? When I try to delete them an error occurs: "Error removing file: Permission denied" I am root. See the image below to know what kind of folders/files.

[image]

thanks

Comment: Did you launch your file explorer as root?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about, I'm new...

Comment: Try going to the terminal at typing in "sudo nautilus", then press enter. Type your password when prompted, this will open the file explorer (nautilus) and give it root permissions

Comment: Sorry, but if you're new, then are you sure you really need to delete these?

Comment: @  user300458 - yes, I am sure.

@ Henry - I will try thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch your file explorer as root using:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

This will open your file explorer, and grant it root, so it should be able to view/delete the directory/file.

If you are like me, and don't care about the warnings in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/11760/300458) you can use this instead:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Comment: `gksudo nautilus` (not `sudo`)

Comment: `sudo` works as well, I never understood why people used `gksudo`, it always caused my more trouble because I needed to install it, as it was not included with my system. And I find it more annoying to have to wait for the window to open, then type in my password, possibly blocking other open windows. I prefer if it just asked for my password in the terminal, it's quicker and less obstructive.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/11760/300458

Comment: Edited my answered to include both `sudo` and `gksudo`

Comment: IT WORKED ONLY WITH GKSUDO

Comment: It's works for me with sudo

Comment: Do **not** use `sudo nautilus`, see this: https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/480481

Answer (score 8):

Try the following: launch Terminal and enter

```
sudo rm -rf '/path/to/locked/folder'
```

And be VERY careful with the path to folder!

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Run command:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
3. Command above would ask for your password.
4. Once the correct password is given, you would give following command.

   ```
   chmod a+rwx folder/file
   ```

   and go to home and just delete the folder/file.
5. Exit for root user type `exit`.

Comment: @Zanna: `sudo su` works on my system and I didn't change the root account or the `sudoers` configuration in a relevant way. But it's unnecessary because one could just run `sudo chmod ...` instead.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I thought I had deleted that comment already! but yes indeed it's completely unnecessary

Comment: This answer is basically the same as kos' but with less detail and worse practices.

Comment: yeah agree with that too

Answer (score 2):

The lock symbol means your user currently have no write permission on the file/folder. To change this:

1. Check the current owner/group/permissions status by right clicking the file/folder, clicking `Properties` and then switching to the `Permissions` tab.
2. Open a `Terminal` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

   - If you are the `Owner` of the file (i.e. the `Owner` field shows your username): add write permission to the owner by running this command: `chmod u+w <path_to_file_folder>`
   - If you are not the `Owner` of the file, but you are in the `Group` group (i.e. the `Group` field shows your username or a name of a group to which you belong, e.g. `sudo`): add write permission to the group by running this command: `sudo chmod g+w <path_to_file_folder>`
   - If you are not the `Owner` of the file and you are not in the `Group` group: add write permission to the others by running this command: `sudo chmod o+w <path_to_file_folder>`
3. Run `exit`

And then just delete the file/folder from `Nautilus`.

Alternatively:

1. Open a `Terminal` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

   - Remove the file/folder as `root` by running this command: `sudo rm -rf <path_to_file_folder>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is something , that I found was easier to do instead of opening terminal. Right-Click the file and open properties. Then switch to the permissions tab. Then wherever it says Access: change it from whatever it is to Create And Delete Files. This should remove the lock and then you can delete the file normally.