# What is sudo nautilus ? What does it do ? When do i use it?

Tags: permissions, nautilus, sudo

Newbie here. I had to install adobe flash plugin and add it to firefox. I followed instructions of a youtube video and did that successfully. In one of the step it asked me to enter the command:

`sudo nautlius`.

I was wondering what does this particular step does and where else can I use it again?

Comment: "I was wondering what does this particular step does and where else can I use it again?" It creates potential issues & you should never use it again. Read the link in above comment or use at worst  `sudo -H nautilus`

Answer (score 2):

nautilus is a file manager in Ubuntu.

sudo is declaring that you are a root (it is something like an adminstrator in Windows).

So, when you type the command `sudo nautilus` , you are entering the file manager as a root. Being root gives you some extra abilities that normal user doesn't have.

Comment: In addention to this and the question:  When do i use it? .... never.

Comment: @Rinzwind why? If you prefer moving files with a graphical user interface instead of via the terminal, this is absolutely the way to go. Am I entering any risks (apart from the danger of me,  deleting root files accidentally) by doing so? If not, what's the issue?

Comment: wait, I actually found a good answer to it already: http://askubuntu.com/a/11766/378854 . So we're not having an actual security risk here, it is more about messing up your home directory.

Comment: @Blauhirn simple: nautilus is a file manager for a -user- so should be used as a user. A user has nothing to edit outside his home and it blocks editing anything a user should not edit. There are some files that need a specific user name and editing it as "root" will change the file to "root" and lock you out of your desktop if you log off.

Comment: And that is why `nautilus` with root privileges should be run with `gksudo`, not `sudo`. As written [HERE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus?noredirect=1&lq=1), `gksudo` prevents from changing owner of files, that were modified.