# Ubuntu 16.10, Firefox and Chromium not working

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser, 16.10

I recently installed 16.10. I have some problems with browsers! The Chromium only works when I open a new window with a temporary profile
 and Firefox gives this error:

> Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.

and the only way to run Firefox is running `sudo firefox` with Terminal.
I removed and installed Firefox again but it didn't solve problem.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Do NOT run Firefox as root/with `sudo`! Never! You may run `firefox -P` to launch its profile manager, where you can create a new profile (and delete the old one if you don't need anything from it any more).

Comment: @ByteCommander What is the problem with `sudo firefox`?  I tried `firefox -P` but the result is `Error: Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.
`

Comment: Please show contents of `~` folder (your home folder).

Comment: @MarkYisri I've added it to the post. Please check it. ^_^

Comment: Now show the contents of the `.mozilla` folder that's in therre.

Comment: Although it looks like @MartinThornton solved  your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have run Firefox with `sudo`, and probably other programs not meant to be, you need to regain the ownership of files in your home directory so they are accessible without root permissions again. This is why you are getting the error:

```
Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.
```

If there is any output from `find ~ \! -user $USER`, and I'm sure there will be, you need to run the command:

```
sudo chown -R faezeh:faezeh ~faezeh
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved!!  How am I supposed to know that I am allowed to use sudo or not? I'm not used to this OS yet! 

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/11766/425479.  You should *never* use `sudo` on GUI programs, and should *only* use it for system maintenance if you know what you are doing.