# I am getting the following errors while using the sudo nautilus command as root. Please suggest a way out

Tags: nautilus

```
root@catherine:/home/catherine/Downloads/cmake-3.8.0-rc2# sudo nautilus

(nautilus:639): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (nautilus:639): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I suggest never using `sudo nautilus`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "gksudo nautilus" and "sudo nautilus"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Comment: @Pilot6: Well, `sudo -H nautilus` may be useful. However, I had a reason to test it the other day and found that it doesn't work properly on 16.10 (but works on 16.04).

Comment: @karel: Same problem in 16.10 with `gksudo nautilus`, btw.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use nautilus as root you should use `gksudo nautilus` instead as the 'gk' provides a graphical front-end for sudo meaning it can be used to safely launch programs that require a GUI

Comment: Please see my comment above about 16.10, though.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson good point however I am using 16.04 and it worked fine for me also when I started writing my answer your comments had not yet appeared

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer. ;) It's probably a bug, and I just provided it as additional info.